# Javascript differences in the expense of function calls under similar conditions

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

I've been grappling over the results of two jsperf's I recently put together and trying to understand the impact of one over the other. Both address the invocation of a function vs doing something inline.

The first jsperf if simple: http://jsperf.com/bool-exp-vs-func-call

In the first case we loop and call a function which evaluates a boolean epxression which is randomly rotated after each call. In the second case we loop and but we evaluate the same boolean expression in the loop directly.

The performance difference here is pretty small in chrome. My last run was 601 (inline) vs 555 (function). Not something I would lose sleep over.

But then there is the curious case of looping which I put into this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/array-traversal-loop-vs-foreach/6

Here I'm only interested in comparing case 1 - which is a raw for loop vs the 3rd case which is 'own foreach'. In case 1 we loop N times and do our work (simply stating the variable). In case 2 we loop N times and call a function to do our work.

But here, the performance difference is pretty massive. 1,717,348 (inline) vs 214,878 (function).

What am I missing?

Comment: Your second test compares a two function calls + object instantiation against two function calls + object instantiation + function instantiation. The function calls are probably insignificant (or inlined anyway), but creating a function object *is* costly (compared to doing nothing).

Comment: Edited - I provided an incorrect link to a different jsperf.

Comment: I'd assume that accessing the global `it` variable is the performance killer here.

Comment: Yes - yea you are right. Edited the test and the results are now comparable: http://jsperf.com/array-traversal-loop-vs-foreach/11 that you for the clarification. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept. I'd also love to understand why that is is that to say defining window.it = function(){} would be this slow as well? (i will test that as well)

Comment: Interesting, I revised the jsperf again http://jsperf.com/array-traversal-loop-vs-foreach/11. Defining window.it2 = function(el){ el;} is comparable to defining function it(){} however, defining a global var it3 = function(){} is (as you pointed out a massive performance killer)

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that there is no function call because it is inlined in this case. Second issue is that even if you make the function [non-inlineable](http://jsperf.com/bool-exp-vs-func-call/2) (in chrome), its code is just sitting in instruction cache and hit very well, so the difference is really hard to see.

For your second jsperf, allocating a new function object is completely different task from calling a function, it's comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Given my error and based on your comments, I would revise the question a bit - given that the function 'it' (in the second updated jsperf) does even less then 'check' in the first - why wouldn't I see similar behavior in chrome? (again apologies for the mistake earlier - I agree apples and oranges there yes)